# React: Making field editable that is also updated from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a form with a phone number field in a React component, I have a situation where the phone number can be changed from outside that input (in this case it's coming from a non-React component that lives in a modal window). The modal window writes its value to a Redux store and the input field in the React component can read that value (connected via react-redux with 'connect').

So, I have tried:

**React Component**

This method makes the field uneditable/read-only:

```
<input type="text" value={phoneNumber} />
```

This method does not update the value when it's changed in the store:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={phoneNumber} />
```

Now I want to be able to update the phone number in the React component and keep it in sync with the Redux store, but what would be the way to approach this?

Comment: I don't recommend keeping it in sync with Redux at all times. Maybe "commit" it to the Redux store after the user is done editing?

Comment: Hi @Li357, could indeed be part of the solution. I think the question would be solved if I can update the field once it has changed in the store.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form.
This one is directly binded to the Redux Store just give the same model name where ever you want the saved value and it will print that value in the input component.

Comment: Hi @HarishSoni, I'm editing an application that is end of life, so I prefer not to use any new libraries to solve this one case ;)

Comment: So you just need to call an action on the onChange event of the Input and save the key strokes in an object .

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the variable `valueFromRedux` is correct and when you save you sync it back to Redux.

```
class Component extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            phoneNumber: valueFromRedux
        }
        this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeHandler(event) {
        this.setState({
            phoneNumber: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
        return <input type="text" value={phoneNumber} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use an `controlled input` which keeps the data in `state` of component. To do this, you should do it like following example.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Code copied from [React Documentation - Controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

You can can your action here in,

1. Use `handleChange`, which will get called every time you do input for the field.
2. Use `handleSubmit`, which will get called once you do submit **(recommended)**

use the data you have in component state to pass it to action. If you are using 2nd method, then your store call will be only once, if user submits the form. This is preferred as each action call is expensive, and could slow down your application performance if store gets larger.